# How can I solve this error (object of type 'float' has no len()), please?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working on the dataset [AMAZON ALEXA REVIEW RATINGS](https://www.kaggle.com/sid321axn/amazon-alexa-reviews)

When I uploaded my dataset as below

```
df_alexa = pd.read_csv('amazon_alexa.tsv', sep='\t')
```

[image]

I wanted to add a new feature, which is called **length**, as shown below

```
df_alexa['length'] = df_alexa['verified_reviews'].apply(len)
```

But, I get the below, error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

**Any assistance, please?**

Comment: Seems like some rows contains `nan` values

Comment: Try something like `df_alexa['verified_reviews'].fillna("").apply(len)`

Comment: Also try `df_alexa['length'] = df_alexa['verified_reviews'].str.len()`.

Comment: And can you print `df_alexa['verified_reviews'].dtype`?

Comment: @9769953 dtype('O')

Comment: Yes, object type. Unfortunately, most of the time, object is also used for strings in Pandas. But it can indicate some numbers (like NaNs indeed) in that column. Also print out the value of `df_alexa['verified_reviews'].isnull().sum()`. Ideally, that is 0, but likely it's not.

Comment: @9769953 i got 1

Comment: So there is one NaN in that column. You can apply Abdul Niyas P M's solution to work around that. Or find that NaN and replace it yourself with a suitable string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this output is caused of the fact that there are sometimes columns where the verified reviews is nan, so you have to calculate the length of the review, if it is a column with nan value it should return 0. So i've created a function to return 0 if it is an empty row. first i wanted to try it with a subset perhaps it would work but i didn't figure it out how to show lines with no reviews.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('amazon_alexa.tsv', sep='\t')
df.dropna(subset=['verified_reviews'], inplace=True)

df['length'] = df['verified_reviews'].apply(len)

print(df)
```

Here beneath the code if there are empty rows and you want to see them.

```
import pandas as pd

def calculate_length(review):
    if pd.notna(review):
        return len(str(review))
    else:
        return 0

df = pd.read_csv('amazon_alexa.tsv', sep='\t')
df['length'] = df['verified_reviews'].apply(calculate_length)

print(df)
```

let me know if it worked and if not please comment